# Wordpress filterable portfolio works on refresh not onclick

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, filter, custom-post-type

I have followed this tutorial to create a filterable portolio: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-filterable-portfolio-with-wordpress-and-jquery--wp-24037

This works fine and everything is cool - then i wanted to adapt this filtering process to a FAQ site i had made - and this is where the trouble begins. When i click one of the filtering tags nothing happens, but if i then refresh the page the filtering action happens. So the filtering process in it self seems to be working - and i am at a lose as to what the problem might be.

Here is the code for the FAQ:

```
<div class="col-md-4 faq-filter">
     <!-- FAQ filter nav -->
     <?php
     $terms = get_terms("tagfaq");
     $count = count($terms);
     $post_counter = 0;


     echo '<ul id="faq-filter portfolio-filter">';
     echo '<li><a href="#all" title="">Alle</a></li>';
          if ( $count > 0 )
             {   
               foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    $termname = strtolower($term->name);
                    $termname = str_replace(' ', '-', $termname);
                    $post_counter++; 
                       if( $post_counter == $count ){
                          echo '<li class="last-term"><a href="#'.$termname.'" title="" rel="'.$termname.'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
                                } 

                        else {
                           echo '<li><a href="#'.$termname.'" title="" rel="'.$termname.'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
                                }
                            }
                        }
      echo "</ul>";
      ?>
      <!-- end FAQ filter nav -->
    </div>

                <div class="col-md-8">

                    <div class="accordion" id="accordion">
                        <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'faq', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); ?>
                        <?php $count =0; ?>

                        <?php if ( $loop ) : while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

                         <?php $postid = get_the_ID(); ?>

                         <?php
                          $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'tagfaq' );
                          $thePostId = $post->ID;                     
                          if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : 
                              $links = array();

                              foreach ( $terms as $term ) 
                              {
                                  $links[] = $term->name;
                              }
                              $links = str_replace(' ', '-', $links); 
                              $tax = join( " ", $links );     
                          else :  
                              $tax = '';  
                          endif;
                          ?>

                           <div class="accordion-section <?php echo strtolower($tax); ?> alle all">
                              <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-<?php echo $postid; ?>"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> <?php the_title(); ?></a>

                              <div id="accordion-<?php echo $postid; ?>" class="accordion-section-content">
                                  <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                              </div><!--end .accordion-section-content-->
                          </div><!--end .accordion-section-->   


                        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div> <!-- Accordian sluttes her-->  

                </div>
```

I am hoping that it might be a simple typo or perhaps a conflict with having two filterable running that might be the problem?

If you should have a different solution to this filtering of my FAQ page that would also be a welcome input!

Any help will be appreciated

UPDATE:
After some fiddling i have been able to get the filtering to work - but now it seems to ignore my tags

Comment: I think one would have to follow the entire tutorial to try to find the error in your code... Does any warning or error shows up in the browser console? Do you have a link to see your code in action?

Comment: You're filtering server side (PHP) rather than client side, so of course there needs to be a page refresh.

Comment: There are no errors :-)
Mervius - there is called a jquery function on the element - so no the filtering is not server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to only call the filterable function on one element - and then call the element the same thing on the two pages. So both ul's ended up with an id="portfolio-list".

There might be a better workaround for this - but it did the trick for me